# Why did Blue Origin make 5 times more flight tests than Virgin Galactic before sending their founders (Jeff Bezos for BO, R. Branson for VG) to space?

Tags: safety, sub-orbital, blue-origin, virgin-galactic

https://twitter.com/blueorigin/status/1413521631717122059 ([mirror](https://archive.ph/KsL5m)):

[image]

Why did Blue Origin make 5 times more flight tests than Virgin Galactic before sending their founders (Jeff Bezos for BO, Richard Branson for VG) to space?

(Notes: as [GdD](https://space.stackexchange.com/users/2981/gdd) mentioned, Blue Origin hasn't sent Bezos yet. This is scheduled for 2021-07-20. Also Richard Branson has not reached the 100 km altitude threshold during his flight on 2021-07-11, and subsequently some may consider that he hasn't been to space).

Comment: Blue Origin hasn't sent Bezos yet.

Comment: @GdD Thank you, I don't know how to phrase the question properly. If I say "before trying to send", then people will argue that they have been trying for years. I'll just add a note.

Comment: Virgin Galactic made a lot of test flights that weren't to space. As as been pointed out before, that graphic is quite misleading.

Comment: One aspect is that their New Shepard rocket does quite a lot bigger job than the SS2 does. It starts from the ground, ascends through 50% more height, and reenters at 4 times the vertical velocity compared to SS2.

Comment: Blue Origin haven't had a single manned test flight before sending their founder! In contrast, all VG flights have been manned as they need the pilots to fly their plane...

Comment: Of possible note is the series of SpaceShipOne test flights, I believe 16 or so crewed including flights above 100km. I believe SS2 is not too much more than a fuselage-stretched SS1, so the earlier design proved out the design and technology that SS2 relies on.